# Showing that $E[X]= \sum \mathbb{P}(X\ge n)$

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

We want to show that $$E[X]= \sum_{n\ge1} \mathbb{P}(X\ge n).$$
We write[image]

there is the one of the possible answer but i don't understand the line 4 to 5.
Indeed when i do it i find :
$\sum_{n=1}^{N} P(x>= n)= 1.P(X>=1)+ 2P(X>=2)+ ... + NP(X>=N)$
$\sum_{n=2}^{N+1} P(x>= n)= 1P(X>=2)+ 2P(X>=3)+ ... +(N-1)P(X>=N)+ NP(X>=N+1)$

I did the soustraction i obtained

-NP(X>= N+1) +$\sum_{n=1}^{N} P(x>= n)$

Comment: Please use appropriate commands like `\ge` $\ge$. Here’s te [MathJax tutorial](https://goo.gl/OWv9nr) if you need to refresh.

Comment: Maybe, [Summation by Parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation_by_parts) can be useful. I didn't try it, so far.

Answer (score 3):

> *... but i don't understand the line 4 to 5*

Just see it is as a telescoping sum
$$
\sum_{n=1}^Nu_n-\sum_{n=2}^{N+1}u_n
$$ with
$$
u_n=nP(X\ge n)
$$ giving
$$
u_1-u_{N+1}.
$$

Comment: i see it is but i don't ibtained the same index.

Comment: Do you see this $$ \sum_{n=1}^Nu_n-\sum_{n=2}^{N+1}u_n=u_1+\sum_{n=2}^{N}u_n-\left(\sum_{n=2}^{N}u_n +u_{N+1}\right)=u_1+\color{red}{\sum_{n=2}^{N}u_n}-\color{red}{\sum_{n=2}^{N}u_n} -u_{N+1}$$ then the red terms cancel.